# angular ssr production issue: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: html, angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, unexpected-token

I have angular project on which I have applied angular universal. I have deployed that on production and I am creating build on production.

I am getting below error when I run application on browser. **This error not comes when I run project locally (`npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr` ). Its coming on production**

[image]

I have searched a lot and I have tried many ways like below but did not work.

1. adding '/' before every path which is in index.html
2. changing text to `<!DOCTYPE html>`
3. Delete /*# sourceMappingURL=bootstrap.min.css.map */ in css/bootstrap.min.css
4. By running `ng build --aot --prod --output-hashing none` is one solution but don't know command in case of ssr build `'npm run build:ssr'`

What should I do to remove that error? please help and guide.

**Edit**

[image: script.js error]
[image: main.js error]

Comment: Click the link on the right of the error message, prettify the result (you can do it within Chrome developer tools itself), then show us where the `<` is coming from

Comment: @CristianTraìna please check edit. I think it's from `scripts.js` and `main.js` files

Comment: You misconfigured your sever. Are the files in the `public` folder? Are you statically serving the `public` folder?

Comment: Also, maybe the problem could be the hashing of the filenames. This is performed in order to prevent caching, but if you have some reference to those files then you could not find them and the server could show you a 404 HTML page

Comment: @CristianTraìna I am using nginx server, there in `/var/www/html` , I have deployed all git files of project and created build on production server in that folder.

Comment: The problem, **in general**, is that your server is not finding the files. It's not clear what the HTML page is, but I'm pretty sure that it is a 404 page or a whitelabel page. So, your problem is reduced to understand why the server is not finding the files. You said that `--output-hashing none` is a possible solution, so check in your `package.json` the `build:ssr` script and see if you can add the flag